# Text formatting tags in ArcGIS, font-size issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, annotation, formatting

I have an old MXD-file, which is imported in ArcGIS Pro (v. 2.9). In our project we are making use of [text formatting tags](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm) to style our annotations.

Now we run into a problem with the font size.
If we take this textstring for example:

```
<CLR red='189' green='0' blue='230'><bol><FNT name='Arial' size='6,5'>TEST</FNT></bol>
```

In ArcMap the text is correctly displayed with a size of "6,5". In ArcGIS Pro however, the text is displayed with the size "65", due to the decimal separator being a comma (","). This is also stated in the ArcGIS pro documentation:

> "Formatting tags use a period as a decimal separator. They do not use
> the locale-specific character."

As I would not like to change the data, my question is: Is there any property or setting in ArcGIS Pro (or ArcMap) so that the annotations are displayed with the correct font size?

Comment: Are these text graphics, or labels? Are they on a map or layout?

Comment: Sorry for the missing info. We are talking about labels and they are on the map.

Comment: If all labels are 6.5pt in size why are you not simply setting them to that size. The html you show is what you might use in the expression. why not simply set the label properties instead? Check out the [help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/labeling-basics.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately not all labels are the same size. There are also font-sizes of e.g 4.5, which are then displayed as size 45. 
My hope was that there is some sort of setting for the "culture" of the decimal separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of telling the application to interpret `6,5` as `6.5` within a label expression, you will need to update the label expression.

This can be automated with some simple python code that steps through each layer in the map looking for `size='6,5'` and resetting it to `size='6.5'`. Below is the code you could run in the python console.

```py
# Update label expression of layers in a map
# Original label class - "<CLR red='189' green='0' blue='230'><bol><FNT name='Arial' size='6,5'>" + "TEST" + "</FNT></bol></CLR>"
# We want to change size='6,5' to size='6.5'
# Author: Duncan Hornby (ddh@geodata.soton.ac.uk)
# Created: 20/9/23

import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
myMap = aprx.activeMap

for lyr in myMap.listLayers():
    if lyr.supports("SHOWLABELS"):
        print("Updating layer " + lyr.name)
        for lblClass in lyr.listLabelClasses():
            currentExp = lblClass.expression
            if "size='6,5'" in currentExp:                
                lblClass.expression = currentExp.replace("size='6,5'", "size='6.5'")
```

Comment: This will do, thank you!

Comment: Is this also possible if working with text graphics instead of labels?

Comment: Text graphics where? Map or Layout? You need to ask another question explaining this, describing what you have done so far. Also have you searched this and the esri forum, you won't be the first to have asked that question...